# Message: Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am having following error when i open my site on IE 8,

```
Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 25
Char: 13
Code: 0
URI: mycode.js
```

mycode.js FILE CODE

```
var LstCompanies = Object.keys(msg);
if (LstCompanies.length > 0) {
```

any ideas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Object.keys doesnt supported in IE.
Here is the safer implementation which is compatible with all browsers..

```
Object.keys = Object.keys || function(o) { 
    var keysArray = []; 
    for(var name in o) { 
        if (o.hasOwnProperty(name)) 
          keysArray.push(name); 
    } 
    return keysArray; 
};
```

Comment: as long as `name` is from `o` in the `for` loop, why test again with `o.hasOwnProperty(name)` please?

Answer (score 2):

Your browser (let me guess, it's Internet Exploder on WinXP?) does not support [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Iterate the old-fashioned way over the object instead.

```
for (var i in msg){
   msg.hasOwnProperty(i){
      // Here you have your keys
   }
}
```

or use the shim mentioned in the MDN article.